# Beginning Lua: How to call functions from terminal on Mac OS?

Tags: function, console, lua, terminal

I'm new to Lua and work around with some tutorials, try some basic stuff like coding common algorithms etc.

But I have some trouble while using the lua interpreter on my mac os machine.

For example let's say we have a file called 'sample.lua', holds the code line:

```
function fib(n) return n<2 and n or fib(n-1)+fib(n-2) end
```

How do I run that function from terminal?
If I don't use any function, I just call the script with 'lua script.lua' - works!

Next question points on the basic understanding between the usage of non-compiled and compiled lua-source. Why is lua code run without compiling, like I mentioned before (lua script.lua)? Or will this statement compile the code temporarily and run afterwards?

Thanks in advance

chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run that function from the terminal, you would have to do something like:

```
lua -e"dofile'sample.lua' print(fib(3))"
```

The -e there just tells it to execute the following string, which loads your file 'sample.lua' and then prints the result of `fib(3)` to stdout.

I don't know the answer to your second question though.

Answer (score 6):

You can run lua from the terminal with the -i flag:

```
lua -i luascript.lua
```

This will execute the script and then put the interpreter into interactive mode. Then you could call the function right from the interactive prompt:

```
fib(3)
```

Comment: this should be the top answer as it accomplishes what @Wallacoloo 's answer gives but in fewer lines, and allows more flexibility in what functions can be run

Answer (score 2):

Lua scripts are always compiled into Lua VM instructions before running. Precompiled scripts just skip this step.

Comment: Can you furthermore explain how to run a compiled lua program from terminal?

Comment: Lua loads both source and precompiled scripts transparently. Just do `lua myscript`.